# Avoiding geo-blocking

Tags: networking, vpn, blocking, geolocation

I'm trying to avoid a Spanish site blocking me because of my location in UK.

I joined [Golden Frog VyperVPN](http://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn) and I could connect to their sever in Spain, so that I can see I have a Spanish IP if I use some IP detection site.

The problem is that, while I'm able to avoid blocking in some sites, the concrete site I'm interested in is still blocking me...

From the VPN provider, they suggest to try to connect from different browsers, clearing the cookies, cache and so on, but nothing is working...

Is there something that the site may be doing to detect I'm actually in UK? And, is there something I can do to avoid that?

Note: I can access the same site from Spain without problems...

Answer (score 2):

The site may be familiar with the major VPN services that have outlets in Spain, and may be blocking those IPs.

You might try getting a VPS or similar hosting solution based in Spain and setting up your own VPN or proxy so you're not using a publicly known VPN server's IP.